# Bluetooth is turned off. Windows Update, Device Manager and Services unable to turn it on

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, dell-xps

Starting yesterday and in the middle of work (not after a specific update), I noticed that my Bluetooth keyboard stopped working. And then saw that Bluetooth is turned off.

So, I tried a few restarts to no avail.

Here is a list of other measures I have taken:

- Windows Update and all the driver updates
- Dell Update of all the drivers' Scan Device Manager for any hardware changes
- Starting all 3 Bluetooth-related services on *Services*

Each measure was followed by a restart.

But despite all, I am unable to turn Bluetooth on. There is no toggle button appearing on *Bluetooth and other devices settings on my Windows*.

I have several Bluetooth devices. So, this is not only about the keyboard. None of the connected Bluetooth devices are working.

Bluetooth does not appear in *Action Center*, either.

**OS:** Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, 10.0.19042 Build 19042

**Laptop:** Dell XPS 13 9380

---

**UPDATE 1**: This is the result of my Bluetooth troubleshooting.

> Device does not have Bluetooth
>
> Bluetooth is not available on this device. Please try using an
> external adapter to add Bluetooth capability to this computer

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: View of Bluetooth devices in Device Manager

[image]

Comment: Check programs and features list for Bluetooth software, if it is there, uninstall it, let windows update reinstall it.

Comment: I've actually done that too, but to no avail.

Comment: Check if there is any unknown USB device under USB in Device manager, if yes, please try to disable it and then enable.

Comment: There is one unknown USB device called `Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)`. I have tried disabling it, updating its driver (there is no new update), and uninstalling it (it pops back up when scanning for hardware changes). I'm not sure if this is the Bluetooth driver. Is there any way of knowing?

Comment: Check the Bluetooth hardware in device manager... Is it functioning?

Comment: @Larryc Please take a look at Update 2. All the devices under Bluetooth seem to have the latest driver. I'm not sure which one of them is the device hardware. And I don't know why I have multiple instances of them. Let me know if there's something I can test judging by the picture.

Comment: Update 2 indicates that the hardware is there and functioning properly. Update 1 (though I'm not sure where you got it) indicates that the hardware doesn't exist. 
Lets back up to the unknown USB device, if you disconnect all usb devices from the machine does that go away? If not then you need to fix that.

Comment: "Unknown device" means that Microsoft couldn't identify the device or find a driver for it.
Right-click on it and select properties, then the details tab. Under property in the pull down menu select Hardware ids. You see a string of characters something like "USB\VID_xxxx&PID_xxxx".  type that exact string into google. this tells you what the device is, and who made it. then go to their website and get the driver. install it and see if that also fixes bluetooth.

Comment: @Larryc Thank you. I did as you said, and under the Hardware Ids' property, I get the value of `USB\DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR_FAILURE`. Could it be that the hardware is damaged and I should buy an external Bluetooth Adapter?

Comment: @Larryc and regarding your comment above the last one, no even when I disconnect all my USBs the *Unknown USB Device* does not go away.

Comment: Well keep in mind that this is a USB device, (not necessarily bluetooth) Descripter failure usually means a hardware problem. I like your idea about an external  BT adapter, it may be your only way out of this..

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem with Windows 10. I have a Asus BT-500 Bluetooth adapter. I downloaded and installed the software package from Asus rebooted and it worked for a few weeks.

All of a sudden windows wouldn't recognize the adapter nor launch the service as it listed as "Bluetooth is turned off" in settings with no slider available to turn it back on. Although the correct drivers were installed & it had worked previously was I stumped.

*My solution* was to:

1. Press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - enter `Services.msc` and double check that all bluetooth services are running and set to automatic.
2. I did not fall back to a system restore. I opened device manager and found my
   device under the USB heading instead of a bluetooth category.
3. I clicked properties then update driver and chose my exact driver software
   installation folder from the manufacturer -  pointing to the appropriate sub-
   folder of the bluetooth installation driver software package.

   (Although it was technically already installed and sure enough it "re-
   installed" my USB dongle and all bluetooth devices immediately)

Hopefully this helps.